# How to have a calculation update automatically with a file with a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a vlookup that I have to update every week with the current date.  Is there a way that this can automatically update?

```
  =VLOOKUP(B26,'C: Inventory\[Inventory Weekly 2018 (08-13).xlsx]Sheet6'!$B:$P,15,FALSE)
```

Is there a way for like next week this file to look at Inventory Weekly 2018 (08-20).xlsx
and the following week Inventory Weekly 2018 (08-27).xlsx
without me having to go in and update it every week manually?

Comment: You cannot do it without INDIRECT and INDIRECT does not work on closed workbooks.

Comment: You could possibly use VBA to build the proper formula string.

Comment: I would definitely vba that and add a weekly recurring task in outlook. to act as a triggering event that makes it to run every week while I'm at lunch.  or at the very least  add a button to my ribbon/quick action bar to make it a one click process